# Use tracker by gnome search provider (for search in 'Activities') | GNOME 3.16

Tags: gnome, nautilus

### edit after @don_crissti comment

Content of my `/usr/share/gnome-shell/search_providers` folder:

```
bijiben-search-provider.ini
gnome-calculator-search-provider.ini
gnome-control-center-search-provider.ini
gnome-software-search-provider.ini
gnome-terminal-search-provider.ini
nautilus-search-provider.ini
org.gnome.clocks.search-provider.ini
org.gnome.Contacts.search-provider.ini
org.gnome.Documents.search-provider.ini
org.gnome.Weather.Application.search-provider.ini
seahorse-search-provider.ini
```

I cannot find tracker.ini so i want make one. The scheme is:

```
[Shell Search Provider]
DesktopId=org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop
BusName=org.gnome.Nautilus
ObjectPath=/org/gnome/Nautilus/SearchProvider
Version=2
```

How make the same for tracker? What is BusName? Why it needs DesktopId?

---

### original question

I would like to add my own directories to the 'places' list in Nautilius file browser. It is not a [duplicate](https://askubuntu.com/questions/285313/how-to-customize-add-remove-folders-directories-the-places-menu-of-ubuntu-13).

The problem is I can remove items from a list deleting them from `~/.config/user-dir.dirs` **but cannot add my own items**.

```
# ~/.config/user-dir.dirs

XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/Desktop"
XDG_DOWNLOAD_DIR="$HOME/Downloads"
XDG_DOCUMENTS_DIR="$HOME/Documents"
# two approaches:
XDG_DROPBOX_DIR="$HOME/DropboxLink"
XDG_FINANCE_DIR="/mnt/V/Users/Mesco/Dropbox/Finance"
```

DropboxLink is symbolic link to Dropbox folder as given above. There is nothing displayed except Recent, Desktop, Downloads, Documents ect.

Tried also:

```
# /etc/xdg/user-dirs.defaults

DESKTOP=Desktop
(...)
DROPBOX=DropboxLink
```

openSuse,
Gnome 3.16.4

PS: I want this because I've read somewhere that in GNOME one **can search for files using "Acitivities" window** only when these files are put in Folders from "Places".

Comment: "places" in `nautilus` side pane are hard-coded so there's no way to do that unless you patch the source code; otoh, `gnome-shell` uses search providers - by default that is `tracker` so you have to add your directory to the list of indexed dirs in `tracker-preferences` and then searching from "activities" will include results from that dir too.

Comment: @don_crissti, good to know! I've change tracker-preferences and it works using tracker, but it is not connected with gnome-shell at all. Especially its not default. I'll edit my question.

Comment: Works fine here without _any_ tracker _ini_ file. I'm on `gnome-shell 3.22`. Yours is a rather old version so might need an [extension like this](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/284/tracker-search/) BTW, the opensuse bit is not relevant, what's relevant is gnome-shell version.

Comment: hmm, I have gnome-shell 3.16 what is not so old. I can upgrade, but would rather keep this stable release.

Comment: @don_crissti I've tried this extension previously but it doesn't work (its quite old last commit 4 years ago - and could not suit to my gnome-shell ver.)

Comment: Well... in the `gnome-shell` world even the previous release is old, so 3.16 _is old_ compared to current, trust me... As to the extensions not working... yeah, they prolly need to be updated to work with 3.16 (this alone should tell you that everything except the current release is old). As I said, it does work on my setup which is up-to-date (`gnome-shell 3.22.2` and `tracker 1.10.1`) but other than that I can't help you as I don't have access to the versions of g-s and tracker you're using there and can't replicate the issue.